# Can I deploy Java web service and SQL database in different host server?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have deployed my database in one server and my Java web service in another server.
I tried to access the database with web service but it doesn't return any rows.

Can I deploy database and Java web service in different servers?

Comment: Short answer:  yes; applications do this all the time.  Long answer:  Yes; are you experiencing any specific application stacks?  Merely not returning rows may be a result of the query as opposed to the connection (which implies the connection is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i deploy database and java web service in different server?

Yes you can, database and web-server are not dependent on each other installation. Just make sure you have the connectivity between the two machines, firewall allows connection on the desired port.

Comment: how can i check my connectivity.

Comment: @user2971245 you can try to do ping/telnet to the ip port .

Comment: i am getting this:
C:\>ping 54.200.224.83

Pinging 54.200.224.83 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 54.200.224.83:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Comment: @user2971245 You are not able to reach 54.200.224.83 server. There may be multiple reasons for it. So check with your network administrator. Few possible reason why ping is failing are 1) Ping may be disbaled on server 54.200.224.83 2) Server is not reachable

Comment: How can i enable ping on server.i have deployed my java web service in amazonEC2.